# Audio file and progress bar

Tags: iphone

I am trying to design an audio player. I need help regarding the progress bar. I want the status of progress bar to change as the audio progresses. I want progress bar to pause as I press Pause button and start again as I press start button. 
Please help...
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [avTouch](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/avTouch/Introduction/Intro.html) code sample. It is an audio player (exactly what you are trying to do), but plays a single file. It implements the progress bar, so this should help..